# Random function that "choose" only the available spots

Tags: python

How to pick an available spot (value = 0) in an array?

```
import random
import numpy as np

board = np.zeros((3, 3))

board[0][1] = 1
board[1][1] = 1
board[2][0] = 1
board[1][1] = 1
board[1][2] = 1


def mark(row, col, player):
    board[row][col] = player


def available(row, col):
    return board[row][col] == 0


rowrandom = random.randint(0, 2)
colrandom = random.randint(0, 2)
if available(rowrandom, colrandom):
    mark(rowrandom, colrandom, 2)


print(board)
```

I need a function that always finds an available location.

Comment: Either repeat your code in a loop, or choose a better data structure that only contains the available positions.

Answer (score 1):

As long as we're dealing with this 3x3 case, the performance is not really a concern, so we can enumerate all the vacant cells and randomly choose from the list:

```
random.choice([
    (row, col) for row in range(3) for col in range(3) 
    if available(row, col)
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get `numpy` to return an array of the indices of all elements in a list which are zero, then use `random.choice` to return one of these indices. For a 1D array this looks like:

```
x = np.array([0,1,0,1,0])
zeros = np.where(x == 0)[0]
# [0,2,4]
x[random.choice(zeros)]
```

For a 2D array, `numpy.where` returns 2 arrays, representing row and column. This example loops over the array, returning an '0' coordinate at random to be replaced, until no '0' coordinates remain:

```
board = np.zeros((3, 3))
board[0][1] = 1
board[1][1] = 1
board[2][0] = 1
board[1][1] = 1
board[1][2] = 1

while True:
    rows, cols = np.where(board == 0)
    # Stop if there are no '0's on the board
    if not len(rows):
        break
    # Pick one of the '0' coords at random
    coord = random.choice(list(zip(rows, cols)))
    # Update it's value
    board[coord[0]][coord[1]] = 5

print(board)
# [[5. 1. 5.]
#  [5. 1. 1.]
#  [1. 5. 5.]]
```

Comment: Your solution returns incorrect results.

Comment: Oops - yes I hadn't 'linked' them as coordinates as you did. Updated to do this, and add a demo of how to loop and update them.

Comment: On the other hand, your tuple deconstruction to rows and cols is more elegant than mine.

Comment: Thanks - I guess the other alternative would be `zip(*np.where(board == 0))` but what it gains on brevity it loses on readability.

Answer (score 1):

As you are storing data in numpy.ndarray, wyo can use numpy to filter out the positions:

```
np_av_pos = np.where(board == 0)
av_pos = list(zip(np_av_pos[0], np_av_pos[1]))
random.choice(av_pos)
```

- `numpy.where` returns a tuple of arrays (one for each axis) containing indices where the condition evaluated to true.
- this is transformed to list of tuples, each corresponing to one position